# The package libpython3.6-stdlib needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, upgrade

```
nitesh@nitesh:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpython3.6-stdlib needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
nitesh@nitesh:~$ sudo apt-get install python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpython3.6-stdlib needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
**nitesh@nitesh:~$** sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.6-stdlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpython3.6-stdlib needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

*I DOWNLOADED THE libpython3.6-stdlib package*

```
nitesh@nitesh:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i /libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-3_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for nitesh: 
dpkg: error processing archive /libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-3_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-3_amd64.deb
nitesh@nitesh:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-3_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 386961 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.5-3) over (3.6.5-5~16.04.york0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64:
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 depends on libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.5-3); however:
  Version of libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 on system is 3.6.5-5~16.04.york0.
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 depends on libreadline7 (>= 7.0~beta); however:
  Package libreadline7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64
nitesh@nitesh:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find any official package available for Ubuntu on packages.ubuntu.com. For your specific package, the result can be found here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpython3.6-stdlib&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

As the search result shows, this package is available for artful, bionic and cosmic. You can choose according to the version of Ubuntu that you are using.

Comment: No. This is not working. I reinstalled ubuntu.!

Comment: @Nitesh Which version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: @Ho Problem was in Ubuntu 16.04 but now I switched to 18.04